# Which API methods require app access tokens

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

Is there a definitive list of which Facebook API methods require app access tokens?

Answer (score 2):

Many needs access token you can find complete detail from here[facebook offical doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

***Thanks..***